# Bitbucket PR showing no changes

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

As the title says my bitbucket pr says there is no diff, however there definitely are differences. I believe the issue is I made branch A, and merged it to develop. There was an issue so I made a new branch B from dev, removed the breaking changes and merged that into develop, (I know I should have reverted, I was silly). Now I am ready to merge A into dev again (no code changes, we had to reconfigure some external service), but when I go to merge it with a PR the PR says there is no diff. I'm assuming this is because the newer changes from B override the changes from A.

What can I do to get the changes from A in? Do I need to re-commit A or something? So far the only way I can see of making it work is creating a new branch from dev, and copy and pasting the changes from A in, and using that, however that seems like a very bad solution.

Comment: Have you pushed your changes from branch B to dev? If you see changes in your commit, but not in bitbucket it might still be local only.
Also check which branch your PR is merging into.~
Hope this helps you out!

Comment: @miva2 I have merged the changes from B to dev, and I can confirm this as dev now doesn't contain the parts of the code that broke it. However if I now raise a pr from A to dev it shows no diff :(

Comment: You can't merge A back again if you already merged it. Git will see that they are the same commits and generate a zero diff, which is what you are seeing.